# YouTube href parameter to open 360 cardboard view

Tags: youtube, google-cardboard

I know I can link to 360 degrees cardboard videos on youtube if I have the app installed.

What I would like to know , is there a param I can add to the url to make the youtube app automatically go into cardboard view, with out me having to press the cardboard button?

thanks.